# Хочу задать константу, которая возвращает все элементы через сервис, но пишет, что она не инициализирована

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

```
private final GameService gameService;
private final List<Game> allGames = gameService.getAllGames();
@GetMapping("/")
  public String homePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("allGames", allGames);
        return "index";
}
```

Выдает такую ошибку, что переменная сервиса не инициализирована!
variable gameService might not have been initialized

Comment: А вы её инициализируете?

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что gameService инициализирует Spring, а конструктор создаётся Lombok аннотацией @RequiredArgsConstructor (скажите, если это не так).

Инициализация полей вроде:

```
private final List<Game> allGames = gameService.getAllGames();
```

срабатывает раньше, чем код конструктора, а в этот момент gameService ещё не инициализирован.

Ну а если конструктора нет совсем, то его нужно создать. Однако, учтите при этом проблему инициализации выше.